# Adding image for blog posts

Tags: django, image, blogs, article

Coding some kind of blog with django, and I can't make homepage to contain images of the articles... It just doesn't upload a image...

my Views.py :

```
class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'add_post.html'
```

my Models.py:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    title_tag = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="YNTN")
    #author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="profile_pics", blank=True, null=True)
    #body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="blog_posts")

    def total_likes(self):
        return self.likes.count()

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.title + " | " + str(self.author))

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("home")
```

My Forms.py:

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'title_tag', 'body', 'image')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Title of the Blog'}),
            'title_tag': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Copy the title with no space and a hyphen in between'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'form-control', 'placeholder':'Content of the Blog'}),
        }
```

and my add_post.html :

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}Make an article{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

    <h1>Make an article</h1>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form method="POST">
            <br/>
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.media }}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button class="btn btn-dark">POST</button>
    </div>
{% else %}
<h1>You are not allowed to post! You need to <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Log in</a> or <a href="{% url 'register' %}">Register</a></h1>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I tried on many ways but never worked..

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"` (as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)) in the form tag inside the html template. Update the html file like this:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <br/>
        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">POST</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: still doesnt work... it's not uploading image to media/profile_pics

Comment: if the form submission is working, then it is uploading the image. You have to make sure the media directory is correct in settings

Comment: You are right... It uploads but in wrong folder... it makes folder for itself...

Comment: This document might help you here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/files/#the-built-in-filesystem-storage-class

Comment: If this answer helps you, consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.